# Validating numeric values in a string. Why is this condition giving true?

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I'm trying to validate string to check is there any numeric value.. but the condition is not giving me expected result. What's the problem ?

```
$data = 'String';

$splt_data = str_split($data);
print_r($splt_data);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($splt_data); $i++) {
    for ($x = 0; $x < 10; $x++) {
        if ($splt_data[$i] == $x) {
            echo "<br> The \"$data\" value is containing numeric value.";
            echo "<br>" . $splt_data[$i] . ' and ' . $x;
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: The output>>>>> 
Array ( [0] => S [1] => t [2] => r [3] => i [4] => n [5] => g ) 1

The "String" value is containing numeric value.

S and 0

Comment: If things are not reproducible, there is no point in dropping the F bomb. Welcome to programming.

Comment: My mistake, I can reproduce this for EOL PHP versions <= 7.4.30 ~ https://3v4l.org/BtR0H. No repro in 8.0.0+

Comment: https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php#saner-string-to-number-comparisons prior to PHP 8 any (non-numeric) string was loosely equal to 0

Comment: FYI PHP 7.4.0 will only receive security fixes until November this year. It's definitely time to update

Comment: Use strict comparison === then. Starting with PHP if you are new to programming is a bad idea!

Comment: not beginner actually i don't understand why is this happening. logically it's should give false value.. But it's giving true.

Comment: _"i don't understand why is this happening"_... did you read the link @apokryfos posted above?

Comment: @nice_dev strict comparison won't work unless OP makes the `$x` numbers into strings

Comment: how can i have expected value ? are you suggesting me to use strict comparison operator.?

Comment: @Phil Actually I meant consistent results logically as OP expects, not necessarily making if conditions truthy. https://3v4l.org/1ageE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about splitting the string and comparing each character, you could use a regex to see if there are any digits in the string:

```php
$data = "String";

if(preg_match("/\\d/", $data)){
    // contains a digit
}
```

Comment: Single \ is enough.

Comment: I clicked Save and the next thing I saw was the green check appearing.    Yours is better.  I do not trust logical values.

Comment: @nice_dev good practice to always escape, escape characters

Comment: @Rylee I am not a great regex guy.  But I would thing escaping the escape would change the escape to a common ASCII character.  There's that logic stuff again.

Comment: @Rylee Not needed for PHP. Use preg_quote if you wish to match regex metacharacters.

Comment: @nice_dev it is needed if you wish to actually include a backslash in ***all*** cases. Why call *another* function when it's unnecessary?

Comment: @Rylee Ya but just \d works just fine. Escaping the character is not needed if it works as intended. \\d is probably derived from Java I presume.

Comment: @nice_dev Why type an extra character that is not needed?  Sorry , my PC does not have a breathalyzer.

Comment: @nice_dev in any case where a backslash preceeds one of [these sequences](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php), it would produce an unexpected result - harder for newer programmers to pickup on. By escaping it to begin with, the proceeding character won't be accidentally escaped.

Comment: In this single use case you can drop it - in production environments, working with multiple members it's far better to ensure you're covered. If you were to change the "d" to another character here and it so happened to be in those escape sequences, this would no longer work as expected.

Comment: @Misunderstood in defence of an extra character - it is far better than calling a function.

Comment: @Rylee Although I am still not convinced, it is fine if you wish to do it this way.

Comment: @nice_dev if you wish to find a backslash using regex, you could not do so using `preg_match("/\\/", $target)`. We are only escaping 1 character here but newer programmers may think they have the regex correct. It is is not as that string would resolve to `'/\/'`. Instead we should always escape the escape character, resulting in: `preg_match("/\\\\/", $target)`. It's best to be consistent throughout your code base.

Comment: @nice_dev same principal as using strict comparisons. It's best to be sure.

Comment: @Rylee I would simply use preg_quote() in such cases to not bother about it. However, the methodology for achieving the results for such cases is opinion-based.

Comment: @nice_dev sure, it's opinion based but you are still creating additional overhead by calling a function when it's not needed. If this were coming from user input instead of being defined within PHP, then it would make more sense.